# How to download yfinance, using pycharm and windows powershell

Tags: python, yfinance

When trying to install yFinance a python plugin, I tried going into my windows powershell to install it using the command

```
pip install yfinance
```

This gives me the error message

```
pip : The term 'pip' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ pip install yfinance
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (pip:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Im using pycharm, and just trying to install yfinance. Is there any other way to install the package or is there any way to fix my problem at hand?

Comment: Isn't there a terminal in pycharm? (Probably on the very bottom row) Run the command there~

Comment: I ran this in the terminal, it gave me a syntax error! please help

Comment: Try `python -m pip install yfinance`

Comment: OH, sorry I was using the python terminalm, when i had to use the vanilla terminal. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

In the PyCharm environemt:
Alt+F12 and then "pip install yfinance"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).